# Unknown function app while merging two Application Insights resources

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-application-insights, azure-data-explorer, kql

So I am in a project where we have a dotnet MVC app inside a React application. We are hosting everything in Azure. The MVC and the React applications are linked to Azure Application Insights resources for monitoring.

I was wondering how I could unify both application insights for my queries in Log Analytics. I went [through this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/unify-app-resource-data). The problem being that I always get an error saying: "unknown function app" when I try to do the following:
[image]
Both resources exist and are in the same resources group. I feel like I am not executing the query from the right scope. I tried executing this same query from the scope of the entire subscription, the complete resource group and from the application's scope.

I was wondering if someone would know how to execute such a query and use the app function.

The linked documentation refers to a "workspace". I think this is the source of my scope problem, since I only tried to run the query from the Azure Monitor page and from the scopes I mentionned previously.

UPDATE
IntelliSense is now aware of the app function, but I get the following error:
[image: error]

Thank you very much for reading my question! I am new to Azure Monitoring!

Comment: Can you just try run this query and see if it can work? The query: `app('your_application_insights').requests`

Comment: I tried the command in a few places. It did not work in a Log Analytics Workspace. However, the app function does work in the application insights of an App Services resource

Comment: What about running it in azure monitor -> logs? I did try it in Azure Monitor or Log Analytics workspace, it can work.

Comment: I just tried again in a workspace and it did work. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, it maybe a sudden server error. I just posted an answer if any other people met the same error, this can help them.

Comment: I get the same error everywhere I try it

Comment: @EduardoCMB Did you try the complete statement (including the .requests? When you start typing app(... do you see intellisense?

Comment: Yes, I had tried with and without .requests. It wasn't working, but now it is. I don't know what happened. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this query in Log Analytics workspace, and it can work well.

You can try just run the query `app('your_application_insights').requests` to see if it can work in Azure Log Analytics / Azure Monitor / Application Insights.

Or this may due to a sudden server error, you can try it later.

Comment: Yeah Intellisense is now aware of the app function, but I still get an error (will update my question with the error)

Comment: @vitonimal, that's weird. You're running it at log Analytics workspace, right? Can you try the same query at Azure Monitor?

Comment: So I tried this query in both Monitor and Log Analytics Workspace and it did not work. However, I tried to run the query from the Logs submenu of an Application Insights resouce and it Worked! I realized that the app function only work when opening a Logs tab (from the Monitoring section of the side bar) that says "Logs (Analytics)" and not only "Logs"

Comment: Oh! I just realized that if I forget the .traces/requests/... at the end it says that the app function is unknown. If I add the .traces it works well in monitor! I guess this is a misleading error message. Thanks @Ivan Yang