# Using application insights data from log analytics

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I'm trying to issue a cross resource query from logs both from ApplicationInsights and from LogAnalytics.

According to the documentation below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/cross-workspace-query

I should be able to open logs from Azure Monitor and use app expression to reference data from one of my ApplicationInsights apps.

But I get an error saying that Unknown function: 'app'.

How to set it up so both logs will be available?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better if you can attach a screenshot of it, so it will help us pinpoint the root cause.

Previously, I provided an answer to a similar issue **Unknown function: 'app'**. Please try to add the table name like **requests** / **traces** at then end of the app expression. The sample query like below:

```
app("your_applicationInsights_name").requests
```

Here is the [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59725608/unknown-function-app-while-merging-two-application-insights-resources) I answered before.

Please let me know if you still have more issues about that.

Comment: Using app expression with the table name still doesn't work. I' ve attached the screenshot.

Comment: Ok, I manged to get it working but it works when I use app expression from particular log analytics workspace.

Comment: @kamilwydrzycki, wow, that's good! And in azure monitor, which scope do you select? you should try to select the scope as the Log analytics, and give it a try.

Comment: and if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks.

Comment: when I limited my scope to log analytics in the monitor it also worked although I had to reference it by appId not by name. I thought that the broader the scope the better. Thank you for your help.